# Repointed domain, can't access site on my PC, but can on mobile.

Tags: dns, point

I re pointed my domain and it works for other people on both their PC and mobile, however when I try to load it on my local connection/wifi, it just loads a page with the words "OK." I suppose all I can do is wait, but not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

When you say others, are they on the same network as you?

Have you tried flushing the DNS on your computer?

Comment: No, other networks. And I'm using Ubuntu, I may be wrong, but I remember reading somewhere that Ubuntu doesn't cache DNS?

Comment: If the update is DNS records for an outside page than I'm afraid all you can really do is wait.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, just wanted to get a confirmation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There may be a couple of factors at play, can we have a little more info.

If this is affecting all computers within your organisation it may be the site has the same name as the domain and the DNS server needs to be manually updated to point to an external website. It may also be that the DNS records has stale records, to manually delete these you have to open up DNS in the advanced view.

If it is just your PC and every other PC in the building can access is you may need to flush your DNS ( Windows Key + R, Type 'cmd' and then hit enter, then type ipconfig /flushdns and hit enter ).

Some routers keep an internal DNS cache, you can normally flush this by restarting the router.

Finally, there may just be a delay in the DNS records propogating globally, you can check the progress using tools like https://www.whatsmydns.net/